# anyone knows the hunt() function in OSE(Operating System Embedded) by ENEA

Tags: function, ose

I read some code, it calls hunt() function of OSE(Operating System Embedded), anyone knows what is the propouse of this function?

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this document [Porting OSE Systems to Linux](http://mdh.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:323508/FULLTEXT01)(PDF), `hunt()` is used to obtain a process ID from a process name for later use in sending signals, etc.

Quote from same, page 7:

> When a process is started in OSE it
>   has to have a name assigned to it.
>   This name is a simple (human readable)
>   text string that can then be used by
>   other processes that wants to
>   communicate with the process. The name
>   is sent to the hunt() call which is
>   used to obtain the ID of the process.
>   The ID can then be used as an address
>   to send signals to.

see also the sample implementation of `send_sig` based on same on page 8.